# php array access issue

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arraws where I'm storing some data: activos[key][value] and pagos[key][value]

the operation I want to do is for each "activo" element get the value and where it coincides with the key on pagos sum the value of this array to a variable.

I've tryed with this but it doesn't work as it is supposed to:

```
$t = 0;
foreach ($activos as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($pagos as $key => $value) {
        if($activos[$value] == $pagos[$key]){
            $t += $pagos[$key]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `;` missing after `$t += $pagos[$key]`;

Comment: well true but there is not the problem, it doesn't do what its supposed

Comment: `$key` & `$value` overwriting here :) see in answer;

Comment: It's rather ambiguous what you want to express with that `activos[key][value]` notation; a `print_r` sample of your actual array would say a lot more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already **key** and **value** from both arrays, but you've erased them !!

```
$t = 0;
foreach ($activos as $keyActivos => $valueActivos) {
    foreach ($pagos as $keyPagos => $valuePagos) {
        if($valueActivos == $keyPagos){
            $t += $valuePagos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This made the solution, tnks!

Answer (score 2):

`$key` & `$value` overwriting here :)

```
$t = 0;
foreach ($activos as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($pagos as $key1 => $value1) {
      if($activos[$value] == $pagos[$key1]){
          $t += $pagos[$key1];
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks this is what you need

```
$t = 0;
foreach ($activos as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($pagos as $key1 => $value1) {
        if($value == $key1){
            $t += $value1;
        }
    }
}
```